# Chrome Extension - chrome.webstore.install is not a function

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have Inline Install of chrome extension on my website, but from few days ago it doesn't work. I have error in console `chrome.webstore.install is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.onclick`.

Actually it works on Mac but not on Windows. Does anybody have similar problem?

Comment: I tried inline install with few other extensions and it doesn't work as well. Looks like it doesn't works with new chrome version (Version 63.0.3239.108)

Answer (score 1):

useing this you can install inline chrome ext.

> < link rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/">

and make sure you need to enable inline installation mode in chrome store console.

Comment: I had conflict with some other extension and that is reason why it doesn't work for me.